# Not able to create variable in JavaFX controller

Tags: java, fxml

I can't add an int at my controller.

This is for my java fxml project.

```
package sample;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {
    public Button calcBTN;
    public javafx.scene.control.Label Label;
    public TextField texta;
    public void pressButton() {
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }
    public void handleBTNAction(){
        String text = texta.getText();
        Integer.parseInt(text);
        Label.setText(text * 84);

    }
}
```

[Faded picture of a giant i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2uJn.png)

> Operator '*' cannot be applied to java.lang.String','init'

Comment: What do you expect the result of `text * 84` to be?

Comment: [`Integer.parseInt()` returns an int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), I think you meant to do this: `int i = Integer.parseInt(text); Label.setText(i * 84);`

Comment: Another question, I saw you added a picture but I couldn't see the context whilst editing, is it relevant to the question?

Comment: So many things wrong here.  One of them is that you should not import `java.awt` classes into a JavaFX project.